# Contrary/Consistent Statements

Tags: logic

This person has been on all seven continents. But this same person has never been to Brazil.

Contrary/Consistent: I would say it's consistent because Brazil is not a continent.

am i right?

Comment: I think it's rather because the continent containing Brazil contains at least one other country.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You just have to reason that a person who has never been to Brazil may nevertheless have been to all seven continents.

Answer (score 0):

I'll take a bit more of a rigorous approch to this:

Brazil is in South America. Therefore, someone having been to Brazil $\to$ he has been to South America. However, this is only a one way implication. That is to say, someone having been to South America $\not\to$ he has been to Brazil.

So even though having been to every continent $\to$ having been to South America, having been to South America $\not\to$ having been to Brazil.